# how to avoid redbox with cross mark error in intractive grid report for a column oracle apex

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I have a interactive grid, where the columns are readonly according to another column condition which and all is working fine..

Whats issue here for me is : there is an redbox with cross mark is showing when page loads for the column readonly.. how to remove that [image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this css rule to your page's inline CSS part:

```
.a-GV-cell.is-error:not(.is-active)::before {
  display: none;
}
.a-GV-cell u-tS is-error{
  color: white !important;
}
```

This will prevent displaying all of that error icons on that page.

Comment: Just copy pasted the same what you mentioned above, but the same error exists , should i need to change anything from your css ?

Comment: my intractive report static id  ::: input_budget_amounts

Comment: could you please have a look in this little

Comment: Crossmark is not showing but the outer redbox mark is still coming

Comment: @Abinnaya Check updated answer please